# How to wait on a Mongo find/map result?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, meteor, callback

I have the following, where Posts is a mongo collection in Meteor:

```
//Tracker.autorun(function() {
    // only return 25 most recent metadata
    var data = Posts.find({}, {
        "limit": 25,
        "sort": {
            "date": -1
        },
        "fields": {
            "metadata": 1
        }
    }).map(function(item) {
        return item.metadata;
    });

    // Asych Race condition! data has not been filled yet. 
    React.renderComponent(new StreamAtom({ "data": data}), document.body);
//});
```

The problem is that "data" has not been returned from Mongo and postprocessed in Map before React tries to render the page. But, I'm not sure how to pass in the "React.render" line to the Mongo.find().map() as a callback. What is the best way for me to wait on the array result that is return from the Mongo find?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first time that the code run they'll be no data, so you need to check for this case and avoid rendering the result (perhaps render a loading indicator instead).

When the data is received the autorun will rerun and you'll have your data.

Normally this sort of problem is resolved by using IronRouter to "waitOn" the data before the page is rendered at all, but we can't tell if this is applicable in your case.

Comment: hi, Meteor specific autorun aside, is there a way to wait on this in javascript?